# JAVA creating ArrayList<String> in a method call.

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm working on a simple program which reads data from a file and puts it in a container defined as a map containing an ArrayList object for each column. The names of the columns are put in an enum.

The problem is, that ArrayLists are raw, and my data is type String.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import static lista3.ColumnName.*;

public class Zad2 {


    //Name,Surname,Salary,District,Position
    Map<ColumnName, ArrayList> columnHolder = new TreeMap<>();

    //combination of a map, holding ArrayLists, represents an extendable table.
    //Notation holder.get(ColumnName c).get(index j) represents getting the value from specified column
    //and row index j

    //an iterable holder of columns
    private final static ColumnName[] ITERABLE_COLUMN_NAMES = ColumnName.values();

    //initialization block for all columns present in ColumnName Enum.
    {
        for (ColumnName c: ITERABLE_COLUMN_NAMES) {
            columnHolder.put(c, new ArrayList<String>());
        }
    }
}
```

My question is- if I put into for loop in initialization block a declaration of an ArrayList object and put it into the map, won't it reference to the same object?

```
//initialization block for all columns present in ColumnName Enum.
    {
        for (ColumnName c: ITERABLE_COLUMN_NAMES) {
            ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
            columnHolder.put(c, a);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The `new` in `new ArrayList<>()` creates a `new` array every time.

Comment: I'm asking if columnHolder.get(key1) will reference to columnHolder.get(key2), if ArrayLists put in the map have a reference to the same object, or not.

Comment: So, even if the name is the same, there will be created as many separated objects, as there is c in ColumnName?

Comment: @Embid123 You mean because all of the arraylists are named `a`?

Comment: Does combining the 2 lines clear things up: `columnHolder.put(c, new ArrayList<String>());`?

Comment: `Map<ColumnName, ArrayList>` should be `Map<ColumnName, ArrayList<String>>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your for loop you're creating an entirely new `ArrayList<String>` everytime, therefore it won't reference to that same `ArrayList<String>` object.

In your code if you already have a key in `columnHolder` which is named `abc` and you're trying to `put` another `ArrayList` under that same name it will override the previous `ArrayList` in `columnHolder` with that name. That's what maps do.